# Javascript Time Counter with flipclock

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I use flip clock JS for count up but when i reload the page time start from zero 
how could i save time like [this](http://piratebay.se/)

```
var clock;      
 $(document).ready(function() {
  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
   clockFace: 'DailyCounter'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution:
Consider that it will not reset days value at the end of the month.
But if you want you can set it to "autoStart: false" and "setInterval"...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date(),
      days = date.getDate()*60*60*24,
      hours = date.getHours()*60*60,
      minutes = date.getMinutes()*60,
      sec = date.getSeconds(),
      clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter'
  });  
  clock.setTime(days+hours+minutes+sec);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/css/flipclock.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="clock"></div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/js/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

[playground](http://jsbin.com/cumovowujo/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: it's true but i don't want to make a random time i want to set passed time from first run of script - are any database required ?

Comment: you can save a cookie ... or create a login and a server database